# How to detect errors from contract calls

Tags: solidity, web3js

```
for (var i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; i++) {
  myContract.methods.contractmanager(i).call().then((res) => {
    console.log(res[0]);
  }):
}
```

There are 2 data stored in my contract. I want to print it but it is not always 2, sometimes there will be more. It is dynamic and I wont know how many there will be.

After executing this code I have 2 output and 2 error. How do I make the loop stop at 2 so it wont show the errors?
How do I detect the error and break the loop?
How do I find out if the output is empty or not?

Comment: It is possible to do that in javascript using [`for await of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) inside a `try {} catch {}`.

Comment: catch does not get the error

Comment: Did you use await? Don't use promise.then().catch(), await and try/catch should work.

Comment: what if you just have a returnAll function in the contract?

Answer (score 2):

You can use async/await.

```
(async function () {
    for await (let i of Array.from(Array(5).keys())) {
        let result= await  myContract.methods.contractmanager(i).call();
        console.log(result);
    }      
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the output type using typeof method. Let's say the datatype of the two output is string:

```
(async () => {
     for(var i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; i++){
       const res = await myContract.methods.contractmanager(i).call();
         if(typeof res=="object" && typeof res[0]=="string" && && typeof res[1]=="string") {
            console.log(res[0], res[1]);
         } else break;
    }
})()
```

Comment: Similar problem that in KFichter answer, javascript won't stop the loop when the promise is called and continue iterating while the call is pending.

Comment: @Ismael You are right. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break the loop when you detect an error then you should use `async` and `await`. For example:

```js
const main = async () => {
  // ... the rest of your code before this

  for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    try {
      const result = await myContract.methods.contractmanager(i).call()
      // handle the result
    } catch (err) {
      break // or handle the error however you'd like
    }
  }
}

main()
```

Comment: One problem is that javascript won't stop the loop at await and continue iterating while the call is pending.

Comment: I don't believe that's true. Await will block if you're just using a standard for loop.

Comment: My fault, you are correct. A promise doesn't stop the loop but the await stops the loop until the promise completes.